# What is this image/gif of Snape and Dumbledore laughing from?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, behind-the-scenes, severus-snape

[image][image]

There's just a split-second snippet of it in the very beginning of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84nUq4uStQA), but it's got to be more than just that. [This page](http://moviepilot.com/posts/3299223) mentions it too, but there's not explanation. Does anyone know where it's from and what they're laughing about?

Comment: It certainly looks like a “behind the scenes” sort of thing, as opposed to a scene from any movie.

Comment: @Adamant hence the tag "behind the scenes". :) Also, it's almost certainly from some type of GoF behind the scenes, IMHO.

Comment: I think it is from *Prisoner of Azkaban*. People at ground level, purple sleeping bags....

Comment: If this is what I think it is, then it's the aftermath of the prank they pulled on Daniel Radcliffe during the filming of PoA. Basically, they put a remote-controlled fartbox in Daniel's sleeping bag, then made sure that a girl he fancied was in the sleeping bag next to him during the scene. I'm sure you can guess what happened next.

Answer (score 20):

### Probably a behind-the-scenes shot from *Prisoner of Azkaban*

Note the purple sleeping bags and faces at ground level, particularly in the still version of this image.  In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Dumbledore conjured a large number of purple sleeping bags for the students after Sirius Black was discovered to have gained entry to the castle.

> Professor Dumbledore paused, about to leave the hall, and said, “Oh,
> yes, you’ll be needing…”
>
> One casual wave of his wand and the long tables flew to the edges of
> the hall and stood themselves against the walls; another wave, and the
> floor was covered with hundreds of squashy purple sleeping bags.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*</sub>

Thus the people lying on the ground in purple sleeping bags is a dead give-away.

The presence of a normally-dressed person holding a clipboard suggests that this is a behind-the-scenes video, as opposed to a blooper or outtake.

As further evidence, note this still, extracted  from the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dU5ejL8KWo0):

[image]

The person crouched down on the left seems to be exactly the same here as in the first image in the question.

A somewhat more complete version of the scene appears in this video at 1:02:

However, it does not appear to indicate which set of extras or behind-the-scenes shots the footage came from.

Comment: This is a good answer. I, too, noticed the "squashy purple sleeping bags" in the first image. I think it's just all good fun behind the scenes. +1 Apropos to nothing, I actually own a purple squashy sleeping bag, that I got from an HP con called Phoenix Rising in 2007. It is very purple and *very* squashy! :)

Comment: That video in the link made me laugh so hard! Thanks for cheering me up :D